# Дебаг режим ANT + IDE. Возможно ли?

Tags: ant, отладка, ide, java

Возможно ли запустить программу в дебаг режиме через ант, но дебажить в IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно можно. Запускаете приложение через ант указав Java-машине приложению ключи

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=7777,server=y -jar application.jar
```

А потом в IDE аттачите отладчик к внешнему процессу. В разных IDE это выглядит несколько по-разному, но в целом идея одна и так же: всегда можно сделать attach к процессу указав порт (7777). Через этот порт вы можете отлаживать даже удалённое приложение (по сети).

Comment: Оу, круто то как. Попробуем... будет работать, поставлю галочку)

Comment: Работает!